# Replace string from certain char to certain char

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string with following content:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:280px">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="/corr/subscription/subscription_1" /></td>
        <td><img src="/corr/subscription/subscription_2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="sub_referat1">#parse ("module/asd")</td>
        <td id="sub_referat2"> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to replace the content between `<td id="sub_referat1">` ... to `</td>` with another string.

The resut shoud be something like: `... <td id="sub_referat1">Max Musterman</td> ...`

I need help please

Comment: ...and your code so far?

Comment: well I'm stuck at replace("sub_referat1>", ">Max Mustermann").
Something I forgot to mention, the ("module/asd") is loaded dyanmically, that means I cannot replace via indexOf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regexp to do that :

```
content = content.replaceAll("(<td id=\"sub_referat1\">).*?(</td>)", "$1Max Mustermann$2");
```

`$1` is the content of the first capture group, `$2` is the content of the second capture group.

`.*?` matches anything, but not greedy (to stop at the first `</td>`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the match before you replace it you could do something like this, where `convert(String)` takes the match and transforms it.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<td\\s+id=\"sub_referat1\">)([^<]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()) {            
    matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, matcher.group(1));
    buffer.append(convert(matcher.group(2)));
}        
matcher.appendTail(buffer);
```